# What is the "correct" way to go from avx/sse masks to avx512 masks?

Tags: c++, sse, avx, avx512

I have some existing avx/sse masks that I got the old way:

```
auto mask_sse = _mm_cmplt_ps(a, b);
auto mask_avx = _mm_cmp_ps(a, b, 17);
```

In some circumstances when mixing old avx code with new avx512 code, I want to convert these old style masks into the new avx512 `__mmask4` or `__mmask8` types.

I tried this:

```
auto mask_avx512 = _mm_cmp_ps_mask(sse_mask, _mm_setzero_ps(), 25/*nge unordered quiet*/);
```

and it seems to work for plain old outputs of comparisons, but I don't think it would capture positive NANs correctly that could have been used with an sse4.1 `_mm_blendv_ps`.

There also is good old `_mm_movemask_ps` but that looks like it puts the mask all the way out in a general purpose register, and I would need to chain it with a `_cvtu32_mask8` to pull it back into one of the dedicated mask registers.

Is there a cleaner way to just directly pull the sign bit out of an old style mask into one of the k registers?

### Example Code:

Here's an example program doing the sort of mask conversion the first way I mentioned above

```
#include "x86intrin.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    auto a = _mm_set_ps(-1, 0, 1, 2);
    auto c = _mm_set_ps(3, 4, 5, 6);

    auto sse_mask    = _mm_cmplt_ps(a, _mm_setzero_ps());
    auto avx512_mask = _mm_cmp_ps_mask(sse_mask, _mm_setzero_ps(), 25);

    alignas(16) float v1[4];
    alignas(16) float v2[4];
    _mm_store_ps(v1, _mm_blendv_ps(a, c, sse_mask));
    _mm_store_ps(v2, _mm_mask_blend_ps(avx512_mask, a, c));

    assert(v1[0] == v2[0]);
    assert(v1[1] == v2[1]);
    assert(v1[2] == v2[2]);
    assert(v1[3] == v2[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [_mm_fpclass_ps_mask](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_fpclass_ps_mask&expand=3209,2030,448,2805,2805) ?

Comment: @PaulR Looks promising, but I dont think it gives me anymore than comparing against zero unordered since negative numbers `FinNeg_res (cid:197) NegNum AND NOT(ExpAllOnes) AND NOT(ZeroNumber);; // -finite` exclude nan/inf and nan `qNaN_res (cid:197) ExpAllOnes AND NOT(MantAllZeros) AND SignalingBit;; // qNaN` ignores the sign entirely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an AVX-512 compare intrinsic to get an AVX-512 mask in the first place (like `_mm_cmp_ps_mask`); that's going to be significantly more efficient than comparing into a vector and then converting it, unless the compiler optimizes away this inefficiency for you.  (Consider using a wrapper library like [Agner Fog's VCL](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) to try to abstract away the difference.  The VCL licence changed recently from GPL to Apache.)

---

But if you *really* need this (e.g. as a stop-gap before you finish optimizing), **you don't need an FP compare**.  `_mm_cmp_ps` in C produces a `__m128` result, but it's not *really* a vector of floats<sup>1</sup>.  It's all-one-bits / all-zero-bits.  You just want the bits, so you're looking for the AVX-512 equivalent of `vmovmskps`, but into a `k` register instead of GP integer.  i.e. [`VPMOVD2M k, x/y/zmm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovb2m:vpmovw2m:vpmovd2m:vpmovq2m) for 32-bit source elements.

```
   __m128 cmpvec = _mm_cmplt_ps(v, _mm_setzero_ps() );
   __mmask8 cmpmask = _mm_movepi32_mask( _mm_castps_si128(cmpvec) );   // <----

// equivalent to comparing into a mask in the first place:
   __mmask8 cmpmask = _mm_cmplt_ps_mask(v, _mm_setzero_ps(), _CMP_LT_OQ);

// equivalent to (if I got this right)
   __mmask8 cmpmask = _mm_fpclass_ps_mask(v, 0x40 | 0x10);  // negative | negative_inf
```

https://uops.info/ is down right now, otherwise I'd check latency and execution ports of VPMOVD2M vs. VCMPPS into mask (for an UNORD predicate) vs. VFPCLASSPS.

---

Footnote 1: You *could* use AVX-512 `vfpclassps` into a mask, or even compare against itself with a `vcmpps` predicate like UNORD to detect NAN or not.  But those are I think slower.

---

> I would need to chain it with a `_cvtu32_mask8` to pull it back into one of the dedicated mask registers.

The way compilers currently do things, `__mmask8` is just a typedef for `unsigned char`, and `__mmask16` is `unsigned short`.  They're freely convertible without intrinsics, for good or ill.  But in asm, it takes a `kmovb k1, eax` instruction to get the data from a GP reg to a k mask reg, and that instruction can only run on port 5 in current CPUs.

Comment: I know I "should" be just generating the new-style masks in the first place. But this is deep inside a bunch of template code that is shared across several ISA extensions, so right now I just want to get the avx and avx512 code playing nicely

Comment: im guessing since we're skylake-x or newer i dont need to worry about bypass delay for the type punning? or is it even less of a concern since its just masks

Comment: @SteveCox: Bypass delay is at worst 1 cycle on SKX, and Agner Fog says VPMOVD2M runs on port 0 with 2-cycle latency, vs. 3 for other into-mask operations so at worst it pays for itself.  I don't know how he measured the 2, though, like what kind of dep chain he created; his instruction tables tend to arbitrarily divide up latency between instructions that cross domain boundaries.   https://uops.info/ is more conservative and shows you the dep-chains they used.  Although with masks it's not so bad because a mask and a vector can both be inputs for the same instruction.

Comment: @SteveCox: But yeah, there might well be bypass latency, depending on whether `vpmovd2m` execution units are wired up to both the FP and integer bypass networks or not the way some other execution units apparently are.  (e.g. the bitwise boolean and shuffle units on port 5, but not the bitwise boolean units on port 0 and 1, as somewhat described in Intel's optimization manual.)

Comment: BTW, for anyone else like me who could not find this instruction (along with fpclass) while browsing [Intel Intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide) it can be found with several other mask manipulation functions under the "Miscellaneous" subsection, NOT under the "Mask" subsection

Comment: @SteveCox: I knew it would have "mask" in the description, so I searched on that in https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ (asm instruction-set list, but each entry has intrinsics at the bottom).  (And that the mnemonic involved "mov"). I always think about these problem in terms of asm instructions first, then how to keep the compiler happy about types and get it to emit the right instructions.

Comment: I also knew it would have mask in the name. So I searched for mask on the intrisics guide and got the entirety of the avx512 extension :P (Someone should really combine the three versions of every intrinsic on there) maybe i should just use felixcloutier.com from now on for avx512

Comment: @SteveCox: Yup, the intrinsics guide is significantly less usable for AVX512.  The flat list format works poorly with 9 versions of everything `{,256,512}{mask,maskz,}`.  OTOH the intrinsics guide is nice if you're looking for intrinsic-only stuff like the `_mm_cast` and `_mm_set` intrinsics, or if you know the instruction name.  It does have some advantages, like having more up-to-date intrinsic names like `_mm_bslli_si128` for byte-shift `pslldq` as well as the older `_mm_slli_si128` name.

Comment: It obviously depends on the code / compiler (this is moreso for GCC). but if either 1) you can build the equivilent logic w.o mask instructions and same cost GCC will almost always do a better job compiling it. 2) the p5 3c latency non-eliminatable move from K -> GP register is hidden from the programmer so make sure you check the assembly because compilers will throw those in unnecissarily without considering their cost.